# Deploying Interbase ToGo on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, delphi, deployment, delphi-xe2, interbase

Here are the conditions for the experiment:

1. Interbase ToGo is licensed
2. Interbase folder including the license folder is in the same folder
   as my multi-platform application called myPgm.app developed
       by Delphi XE2 as HD-FMX application.

When right-click over myPgm.app and from the drop-down menu choose Show Package Contents I am getting the following listing:

Contents

```
Info.plist
Mac
    myPgm
    myPgm.rsm
    libcgunwind.1.0.dylib
    libibtogo.dylib
Resources
    Icon.icns
```

After quite bit experiments with trying to run Interbase based application on Mac OS X I made the following observations:

- If DatabaseName property of the Interbase component doesn’t have any value, myPgm.app shows message: “Database name is missing”
- If I fill up that property with any value either wrong or right I am getting message: “product INTERBASE in not licensed”.

Following the logic that when the server is not embedded DatabaseName has to start with localhost: or actual address of the server I am suspecting Embarcadero planned the developer to put some “magic” word at the beginning of the actual .ib or .gbd file.

I am looking to find solution how to connect myPgm.app with myIBDb.ib, which is in the same folder as myPgm.app.

It is so pity Embarcadero sells these ToGo licenses (I purchased one for $60) and there are no guidelines about specifying the path and the name of the database on Mac OS X. Contrary on Win system there is no problem what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have to provide the answer myself. It came after back and forth exchange of messages with support personnel at Embarcadero. As you can sense from my question I got the feelings that it is a path issue from the beginning. In the spirit of FireMonkey I was playing “monkey” by plugging interbase folder everywhere but the last place that it never occur to me putting it was the bottom of hierarchy of package contents, namely inside MacOS folder. By being a Mac application I thought it will follow the guidelines from Apple about the root path for an application bundle – the level of .app file – but no. See the snapshot for the contents of the package. (sorry I don't have privileges to post images)

Now thankfully to Embarcadero one can develop with confidence desktop database driven applications thus creating alternative to the only desktop player – FileMaker. Keep in mind that there is no MS Access database for Mac OS.